# Load an ArrayList with nested ArrayLists from a file using Java

Tags: java, arraylist, nested, filereader, filewriter

I have an arraylist like `ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>`. I have saved my main ArrayList in a text file by using the following code.

```
 ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> ar2 = new ArrayList<>();
 FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("path/to/the/text/file");
        for(ArrayList<String> str: ar2) {
            writer.write(str + System.lineSeparator());

        }
        writer.close();
```

Now, I want to load the saved data from the file to the same `ArrayList ar2` in every new run. I tried several methods but the nested arraylists are loaded as Strings. How can I overcome from this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the file contents, split by line separator and then remove the brackets and split again to get the list items. Something like

```
File file = new File("path/to/the/text/file");
FileReader reader = new FileReader(file);

char[] chars = new char[(int) file.length()];
reader.read(chars);

String fileContent = new String(chars);
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> readList = new ArrayList<>();

String[] splittedArr = fileContent.split(System.lineSeparator());
for(String list : splittedArr) {
    list = list.replace("[", "").replace("]", ""); //removing brackets as the file will have list as [a, b, c]
    List<String> asList = Arrays.asList(list.split(", "));//splitting the elements by comma and space
    readList.add(new ArrayList<>(asList));
}
reader.close();
```

Answer (score 1):

Either you can parse the string and convert it to an Array using iteration or you can use a library that will do it for you.

I would recommend using Jackson, you can find an easy tutorial [here](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-object-mapper-tutorial).